# Is it possible to have mulitple front-ends for a single DSpace instance?

Tags: dspace

Is it possible to have multiple front-ends for a single instance of Dspace? For example, have an instance of Dspace but have 4 different front-ends (newsxmlui.xml) one for each campus pointing to it.

I am running DSpace 5.2 with Mirage 2 on CentOS 6.

This doesn’t seem possible with the current architecture, but I just wanted to check to see if I was missing something.

Thanks,
susan

Comment: How will each front end differ?  You can create community specific themes that can look very different.  If you look at the code for the mobile xmlui theme, it might provide a model for creating different themes for different subdomains.

Comment: Each front end will service its own community have it's own URL, header logo, search facets etc. When someone does a search they are only getting items from that particular community without having the "check" the box for "This community only".

Comment: The answer from @kardeiz should help with the URL resolution.  The rest could be accomplished with custom themes.  Your custom theme will need to suppress the options to search/browse the entire repo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @terrywb notes, creating separate themes per community/collection might be sufficient for your needs.

Although I've never used it, I believe you can use `themes.xmap` and the `xmlui.theme.allowoverrides` config setting to mount specific themes at specific mount points (URL paths). See [`ThemeMatcher.java`](https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/master/dspace-xmlui/src/main/java/org/dspace/app/xmlui/cocoon/ThemeMatcher.java) and [`themes.xmap`](https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/master/dspace-xmlui/src/main/webapp/themes/themes.xmap) for more information. You could place a block in `themes.xmap` like:

```
<map:match type="ThemeMatcher">
  <map:mount uri-prefix="dept1/" src="Dept1Theme"/>
  <map:mount uri-prefix="dept2/" src="Dept2Theme"/>
</map:match>
```